# Binding TextBlock to a log file in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application that is output the log to a log file. The log file is being written to. I want to display the contents of the log file into a `textBlock` on the UI

```
 <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LogViewStyle}" 
                       Text="{Binding LogMessage,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"
                       x:Name="LogView" Foreground="White" 
                       FontFamily="Consolas" 
                       RenderTransformOrigin="0.415,0.382" 
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,172,10,0"/>
```

The code is shown below. Somehow the TextBlock is not getting updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        static string configFile = "si_config.yaml";

        static string logFilePath = "C:\\si_data\\logs\\";
        NotifyIcon nIcon = new NotifyIcon();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyV V = ConfigFileManager.CreateTVFromConfigFile(configFile, logFilePath);
            List<MyV> fV = ConfigFileManager.CreateFVFromConfigFile(configFile, logFilePath);

            ReadFile(logFilePath + "ms_interface.log");

            FVDataBinding.ItemsSource = fighterVehicles;
        }

        private string _fileText;
        public string FileText {
            get
            {
                return _fileText;
            }
            set {
                if (string.Equals(value, _fileText))
                    return;
                _fileText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileText");
            }
        }
        public void ReadFile(string path)
        {
            FileText = File.ReadAllText(path);
            OnPropertyChanged("FileText");
        }


        //INotifyPropertyChanged members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

         private void FVDataBinding_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor changes to the directory where the log file is located. Then the file is updated, load its contents. Make sure not to lock the file when reading as this may cause adverse effects for the applications writing to it.

Comment: @Nkosi - for some reason my binding itself doesn't seem to work

Comment: The text box is binding to `LogMessage`, I see no property exposed that matches that name. Did you mean to bind to `FileText`? I also do not see where the `DataContext` is being set

Comment: @Nkosi - how do I set the DataContext?

Comment: In the constructor right after `InitializeComponent();` set `this.DataContext = this;` how ever I would advise you create a view model that encapsulates your desired behavior and bind to that

Comment: @Nkosi -  
It is now displaying the log file. But it is not updating as the log file gets updated

Comment: Again, you need to create a mechanism that is monitoring the file location and then read the file contents again to refresh the view

Answer (score 2):

Bind to the `FileText` property:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LogViewStyle}" 
                       Text="{Binding FileText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"
                       x:Name="LogView" Foreground="White" 
                       FontFamily="Consolas" 
                       RenderTransformOrigin="0.415,0.382" 
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,172,10,0"/>
```

It is this one that you set in `ReadFile` method. There is no property called `LogMessage`.

And you don't have to set the `DataContext` of the window since you are specifying the source of the binding explicitly.

Comment: It is now displaying the log file. But it is not updating as the log file gets updated.

Comment: Maybe that's because your code only calls the ReadFile method once.